# How can make this web app mobile responsive

Tags: reactjs, responsiveness

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YV4LB.png)

I make this web app using react.js and I tried very much to do Responsive for mobile devices but I couldn't, any one solve this problem please.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I used useMediaQuery from material ui which helps very much in creating responsive site.

Here is the [documentation](https://mui.com/components/use-media-query/#main-content) for it.

After then for displaying responsive components

1. You can create new components that are fit to that window size
2. You can use states for toggling for the different window sizes

And then you can import them as you want.